# No access to sitecollection root, but all Pages and Subsites works fine

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, access-denied

I have an intranet-solution which is a webapp with one site collection which is available under `servername.domain.local`

I played around with anonymous-access and suddenly I have the problem that if the users navigate to the url above they get

> Sorry, this page in not accessible for you

(We have the german version and I dind't find the right translation. It is the message you get if you don't have access to a page)

But, if the users open the full URL of the homepage `....ain.local/SitePages/homepage.aspx` everything works fine.

Maybe there is something broken with the user-rights? Is there a way to reset the access-settings completely?

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

I made some mistakes while configuring AAM URL's! After reseting the AAM-URL's, deleting the old IIS-Websites and creating new IIS-Websites and using these as AAM it started working again